# Get deployed contract dynamically in node JS

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, nodejs, explorer-api

I am using Node JS and ethereum smart-contract. Every time contract gets deployed new addresses generated.

Is there a way that node JS always gets an updated address of a contract? Any API so that I don't have to go and update in node to connect contract through new address every time I deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you register your contract with Ethereum Name System (ENS) during the deployment.

- Create an ENS name
- Update its ADDRESS record to point to the latest contract deployment during the deployment

https://medium.com/the-ethereum-name-service/new-text-records-now-available-for-ens-names-in-manager-a0ebb9cda73a

You can do this programmatically from JavaScript.